Back EMF in electromagnetic coil
I am  trying to quantify the back EMF generated while actuating an electromagnetic coil, this would be included in a general calculation  to estimate the coil output under a variety of conditions. My background is not electrical, so please forgive any lack of clarity in stating the question; to summarize the problem:

I am actuating an solenoid coil actuator by applying a given voltage, let's say 12V.

The coil-generated magnetic field displaces an armature, which, in turn, moves another component


Is there an EMF generated (per Lenz's law), which opposes the change of magnetic field (which was =0 at t=o) ?
If so how do I quantify it? Assume the coil inductance and general characteristics are known, would dI/dt be the rate of change of applied current? (meaning the time it takes to go from I=0 to I=peak current)



Is there an EMF generated (per Lenz's law), which opposes the change
of magnetic field (which was =0 at t=o) ?

Yes, a back emf is generated when there is any change in current flow and this does not just apply to AC circuits and includes things like your example, where the current changes, when a DC circuit is energised.

If so how do I quantify it?
The current (a) as a function of time is given by $$a = I_{peak}\left(1-\exp\left(-t\frac{R}{L}\right)\right),$$

where $I_{peak}$ is the maximum current through the coil determined by $I_{peak}$ = V/R and V is the battery voltage applied to the coil. R is the resistance of the coil and and any other resistors in series with the coil. L is the inductance of the coil and this is a constant.
Solving for t gives: $$t = \frac{L}{R}\left(\ln\left(\frac{I_{peak}}{I_{peak}-a}\right) \right) \ ,$$
The time for the current passing through the coil to rise to the maximum current (so a=$I_{peak}$) is infinite. However, there is handy aproximation that the time for the current to rise to 99% of the maximum current is given by: $$t_{0.99I_{peak}} \approx \frac{5L}{R}$$  which is much more convenient for practical purposes. Ref Electrical Engineering: Ch 7: Inductors (7 of 24) DC Current Through an Inductor

Thanks ! Would it be correct then, to state that the induced voltage
at any given time is Vi = V(exp(-Rt/L)) ? Where V is the voltage of
the supply ? With Vi being some kind of exponentially decaying
function – Stefano

Yes, I agree. Using your notation where $V_i$ is the back emf and starting with initial equation at the top and replacing current with V/R we have: $$\frac{(V-V_i)}{R} = \frac{V}{R}\left(1-\exp\left(-t\frac{R}{L}\right)\right)$$ and solving for $V_i$ gives: $$V_i = V\left(\exp\left(-tR/L\right)\right)$$

The above is a Wolfram alpha plot of the decaying induced voltage as a function of time and L=50.
I see you have watched the linked video lecture and understood it, because you picked up on my typo in the first equation, which I have now corrected ;-)

Thanks ! Would it be correct then, to state that the induced voltage at any given time is Vi = V(exp(-Rt/L)) ? Where V is the voltage of the supply ? With Vi being some kind of exponentially decaying function

@Stefano I have extended my answer to answer your comment and corrected a typo in the first equation. Thanks for the subtle prod :-)
